# Why Temporary GCS bucket is needed to write a dataframe to BigQuery: pyspark

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, pybigquery

Recently I face an issue while writing the dataframe data into BigQuery using pyspark. Here it was:

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Temporary or persistent GCS bucket must be informed

After research the issue I found that Temporary GCS bucket to be mentioned `spark.conf`.

```
bucket = "temp_bucket"
spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)
```

I think there is no concept to have a file for a table in Biquery like Hive.

I would like to know more about it, why we need to have temp-gcs-bucket to write the data into bigquery?

I was searching for the reason behind this but I couldn't.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Spark BigQuery connector has two write modes(writeMethod), 1. Direct 2.Indirect   while writing data into BigQuery. This is a optional parameter, default is Indirect.

**Indirect**
You can specify indirect option like this `option("writeMethod","indirect")`. Its optional, and Indirect is default. This requires you to specify a temporary gcs bucket, if not you will get the error.
The need of temporary bucket is .

> The connector writes the data to BigQuery by first buffering all the
> data into a Cloud Storage temporary table. Then it copies all data
> from into BigQuery in one operation.

Taken from the GCFS spark example docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example#reading_and_writing_data_from_bigquery)

**Direct**

In this method the data is written directly to BigQuery using the [BigQuery Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api)

In scala you can specify like this `option("writeMethod","direct")`. which eliminates the need for a temporary bucket.

You can read more about the bigquery connector [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector)